# Facebook, StaticHTML and form summission

Tags: html, facebook, object, iframe

This is weird!

I have set up a form using RapidMailer, and on an external site it works fine. (Just to complicate matters, the form is within a <div> as I display a background image, and then use the <div> to position the signup box halfway down the page)

But ...

Put it within an Facebook (Thunderpenny) StaticHTML page, (which I think is <iframe>?) and whilst I can enter name/email, and the submit button shows mouse up/mouse down events, it just won't submit.

I tried adding "pointer-event:auto" to the div so that it was to the fore, but no go. And no good asking the app creator as I doubt I'll get a response. Anyone any ideas? (** I could include page code, but it's 90% links to external js files Rapidmailer sets up)

Is it 'cos I got a <div> within an <iframe>? Do I need to add an <object> to the code somewhere???

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that for some reason, the HTML code cannot find / use the javascripts even with direct URL's. I strongly suspect it's to do with "cross browser" limitations. In otherwords, the StaticHTML <iframe> is on one server, and the HTML code is trying to access javascript on a second server. And as the RapidMailer script is using three scripts direct from jquery.com, it's difficult to know what can be eliminated as they all contain error trapping routines.

In the end, I had to add a direct link to a status update on the Facebook page, and redirect it to the signup form on my blog. I then pinned the post the top. Alas, now for some reason it won't display a graphic with the link, and instead insists on showing the URL  itself! Oh well!